# How to get total duration in Django

Tags: python, django, python-datetime, duration

I am trying to display duration time for an particular work.

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    
    @property
    def duration(self):
        if not (self.start_date and self.end_date): 
            return None
        a,b=self.start_date, self.end_date
        return '%s:%s' % ((b-a).days*24 + (b-a).seconds//3600, (b-a).seconds%3600//60)
```

But while i call **duration** property for getting total time, it's give *unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date'* error.

How can i get the duration date please from my **UserData** model?

Comment: Use both DateField `auto_now_add` or `default=timezone.now`

Comment: If i use `auto_now_add` for both field, i will not get *duration* , both will get same time. because as [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)

Comment: one is `DateTimeField` and the other is `DateField`. The difference between these 2 will not be accurate. The duration will always be calculated from midnight.

Comment: @VishalSingh ,Yah, you are right. I got the point. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two solutions.

1. Use start_date and end_date both as DateTime Fields.
2. a,b=self.start_date, self.end_date.date(). use end_date to date only.

hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have used `start_date and end_date both as DateTime Fields.` And one is `auto_now_add=True` another one is `auto_now=True`  And i am able to see the duration.

Comment: I am getting only Hours for duration, For example : `48:0` hrs. how can i get minutes and seconds from my duration property ? Thank you.